ESP-32 I2S configuration for INMP441 MEMS microphone?
I'm trying to capture audio from an INMP441 microphone (datasheet) using the following code:
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>

#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_event.h>
#include <esp_netif.h>
#include <mqtt_client.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>

#include <driver/gpio.h>
#include <driver/i2s_std.h>

#include "wifi.h"
#include "mqtt.h"

#define BUFLEN      2048
#define SAMP_RATE   8000

#define I2S_WS  GPIO_NUM_25
#define I2S_SD  GPIO_NUM_33
#define I2S_SCK GPIO_NUM_32

const static char *TAG = "app";

static i2s_chan_handle_t chan;
static esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client;

static void i2s_read_task(void *args)
{
    size_t n;
    char *buf = calloc(1, BUFLEN);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_channel_enable(chan));

    for (;;) {
        if (i2s_channel_read(chan, buf, BUFLEN, &n, 1000) == ESP_OK) {
            if (n > 0)
                esp_mqtt_client_publish(client, "snd", buf, n, 1, 0);
        } else
            printf("Read Task: i2s read failed\n");
    }

    free(buf);
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

static inline void i2s_init(void)
{
    i2s_chan_config_t chan_cfg = I2S_CHANNEL_DEFAULT_CONFIG(
        I2S_NUM_AUTO,
        I2S_ROLE_MASTER);

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_new_channel(&chan_cfg, NULL, &chan));

    i2s_std_config_t std_cfg = {
        .clk_cfg = I2S_STD_CLK_DEFAULT_CONFIG(SAMP_RATE),
        .slot_cfg = I2S_STD_MSB_SLOT_DEFAULT_CONFIG(
            I2S_DATA_BIT_WIDTH_24BIT,
            I2S_SLOT_MODE_MONO),
        .gpio_cfg = {
            .ws = I2S_WS,
            .din = I2S_SD,
            .bclk = I2S_SCK,
            .dout = I2S_GPIO_UNUSED,
            .mclk = I2S_GPIO_UNUSED,
            .invert_flags = {
                .ws_inv = false,
                .bclk_inv = false,
                .mclk_inv = false
            }   
        }
    };  

    std_cfg.clk_cfg.mclk_multiple = I2S_MCLK_MULTIPLE_384;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2s_channel_init_std_mode(chan, &std_cfg));
}

void app_main(void)
{
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    wifi_connect();
    client = mqtt_init();

    i2s_init();
    xTaskCreate(i2s_read_task, "i2s_read_task", 4096, NULL, 5, NULL);

    for (;;)
        vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

I'm getting sound, but with quite a bit of noise. I couldn't find any examples that use the newer ESP-IDF. I'm using ESP-IDF v5.2.1.

A few common sources of audio noise are:

Insufficient sample rate
Insufficient buffer size
Insufficient and/or irregularly spaced CPU cycles allocated to the
sound task
Mismatching sample rate and/or data format

Your investigation should consider these and other possibilities.
One thing that stands out to me is that you are directly publishing the received audio data via MQTT in the same task where you are polling it via the I2S driver. I can imagine this easily leading to a manifestation of issue #3 above, where the act of sending an MQTT message blocks your audio task just long enough to cause you to miss a bit of data, resulting in noise. A first step to addressing this would be to decouple the audio input from the MQTT output, perhaps by queuing the audio input data onto another buffer and letting a second FreeRTOS task handle dequeuing it and sending it asynchronously down to MQTT.

Thank you very much for the pointers, I'll investigate those. I was going through the ESP-IDF docs, and noticed that 24-bit deep I2S data seem to be stored in the high 24 bits of a 32-bit cell. I wasn't trying to handle that, I'm trying to get that sorted now as well.
